# Mongoose Express.js delete object with relationships

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

So i have schema Town and i want to delete one town with all ads in it and all relashionships to ads.Here are my schemas:

```
let adSchema = mongoose.Schema (
{
    author: {type: ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
    category: {type: ObjectId, ref: 'Category', required: true},
    town: {type: ObjectId, ref: 'Town', required: true},
}
```

);

```
let categorySchema = mongoose.Schema (
{
    name: {type: String, required:true, unique: true},
    ads: [{type: ObjectId, ref: 'Ad'}]
}
```

);

```
let townSchema = mongoose.Schema (
{
    name: {type: String, required:true, unique:true},
    ads: [{type: ObjectId, ref: 'Ad'}]
}
```

);

```
let userSchema = mongoose.Schema(
{
    email: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
    ads: [{type: ObjectId, ref: 'Ad'}],
}
```

);

i am using this code to do this:

```
let id = req.params.id;
    Town.findByIdAndRemove(id).populate('ads').then(town => {
        let ads = town.ads;
        if (ads.length !== 0) {
            ads.forEach(ad => {
                Ad.findByIdAndRemove(ad.id).populate('author category').then(ad => {
                    let author = ad.author;
                    let category = ad.category;
                    let authorIndex = author.ads.indexOf(ad.id);
                    let categoryIndex = category.ads.indexOf(ad.id);

                    category.ads.splice(categoryIndex,1);
                    category.save(err => {
                        if (err) console.log(err);
                    });
                    author.ads.splice(authorIndex, 1);
                    author.save().then(() => {
                        res.redirect('towns');
                    })
                })
            });
        } else {
            res.redirect('/');
        }
    })
```

Actually everything is working and everything is deleted as it should be but it throw me error(when i am trying to delete town with ads in it) in console and stuck on redirecting.This is the error:

> (node:10200) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "towns" at path "_id" for model "Town"
>   (node:10200) DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in redirecting path.It should be like the one in the else scope:

```
            res.redirect('/');
```